# How can I set a property on every ancestor item on a tree branch?

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a simple project management system, and I have this model for a project:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public List<Project> ChildProjects { get; set; }
}
```

It is defined like this in `OnModelCreating()`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
    .HasMany(c => c.ChildProjects)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);
```

I want to have some functionality to change the `Completed`-property for all ancestral projects if it needs to be changed. I.e. if all sibling child projects of a particular parent project is set to completed, the `Completed`-property of the parent project should automatically be set to `true`. And then the same check for grandparent, great grand parent, and so on.

This is what I have:

When creating or updating a child project, I'm also doing this:

```
// "project" is the current project we are creating or updating.
if (project.ParentId != null)
{
    List<Project> allProjects = await db.Projects.ToListAsync();
    List<Project> siblings = allProjects.Where(s => s.ParentId == project.ParentId).ToList();
    SetParentCompleteness(allProjects, project.Id, siblings.All(c => c.Completed));
    db.UpdateRange(allProjects);
}
```

The `SetParentCompleteness()`-method:

```
private void SetParentCompleteness(List<Project> allProjects, int id, bool completed)
{
    Project project = allProjects.Where(p => p.ParentId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (project != null)
    { 
        project.Completed = completed;
        db.Update(project);
        SetParentCompleteness(allProjects, project.Id, completed);
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm aware that it's not a good idea to `UpdateRange(the_entire_database)`. How can I make a list of just the projects that needs to change?

Comment: Seems like reasonable logic but why would you write `db.Projects.ToList()` that's a very bad idea. Don't do so many eager evaluations. Also, you can get siblings like this. `project.Parent.Children` which is much simpler. You'll need lazy loading

Comment: @AluanHaddad What is the alternative to `db.Projects.ToListAsync()` if I want all the projects in the database?

Comment: You don't need them all, only the ones that are associated with the project being updated

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the logic into 3 parts.

Part 1: you want to query all related projects (your tree). For this, yes, you want to load all projects from DB, but actually, you need to load ProjectID, ParentID, and status only. You don't need to load whole entity (in case your project entity got many columns).

Part 2: change status for all queried projects. For those loaded IDs, now, you can load all needed project (whole entity this time) and change the status.

Part 3: bulk update for all projects. You can use something like this (https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-update) to optimize updating performance.